# MediaPlayer with multiple SurfaceViews

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer

I have a mediaplayer that is acting as a service and would like to change the display surfaceview and have the video continue in a different activity.

In the documentation it states that I can call setDisplay in any state of the mediaplayer and when setting the display on ICS i get a blinking image of the video. Only way i get to see the video is by pulling down the notification bar a bit or performing some action causing for pixels to be drawn like changing the volume.

The setup is simple... 
Activity A | bind to service instantiate mediaplayer attach surface and play video. 
Click link in activity A so open Activity B...
bind to service make sure video is currently playing and setDisplay to different surfaceview.

I tried setting visibility to surfaceview to invisible/gone in previous activity... calling setDisplay(null) first.... pausing then resuming the video.. and turned off the drawing cache.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Video on android is absolutely horrible. The MediaPlayer object should hold a private variable for state which can be checked. Also the error codes are extremely vague. VideoView itself is not helpful unless u want to play a video and thats it. Basically it is never trivial to manipulate a surfaceview which i am assuming is because the surfaceview draws differently than a regular view.

Comment: I am sorry I do not have a better explanation but this seems to have been fixed by only placing setDisplay(null). I had a callback where i set the surfaceview visibility to hidden when the surfaceDestroyed callback was called. After removing it the flickering stopped. Now this only works on ICS and on the galaxy note (non ICS) all i have is a black screen with the audio playing in the bg. So i still need help if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TextureView for the display and use mediaPlayer.setSurface instead of mediaPlayer.setDisplay.

From Activity A invoke simply Activity B and pass the video position parameter.
In Activity B - when the surface is available set it into the MediaPlayer and hit start.

I don't see any reason why it could fail unless there are stuff that happening with the media player that you are missing.

and yes, Android is horrible(not only in manipulating videos).

Here is my code for VideoFullScreenActivity

```
public class FullScreenVideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    private EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
    private CustomVideoView mAdapterVideoPlayer;
    private TextureView mFullScreenTextureView;
    private RelativeLayout container;
    private boolean mIsPortrait;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen_video);

        container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        mFullScreenTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_texture_surface);
        mFullScreenTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!bus.isRegistered(this))
            bus.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (bus.isRegistered(this))
            bus.unregister(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (mAdapterVideoPlayer != null)
            mAdapterVideoPlayer.setSeekPosition(PiplMediaPlayer.getInstance().getCurrentPosition());
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void fullscreen(VideFullscreenParams videFullscreenParams) {
        this.mAdapterVideoPlayer = videFullscreenParams.customVideoView;

        mIsPortrait = videFullscreenParams.customVideoView.getWidth() < videFullscreenParams.customVideoView.getHeight();
        if (mIsPortrait)
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        CustomMediaPlayer.getInstance().changeSurface(new Surface(surface));
        CustomMediaPlayer.getInstance().prepareController(container);
        CustomMediaPlayer.getInstance().setControllerTouchView(mFullScreenTextureView);
        CustomMediaPlayer.getInstance().start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    }

    public static class VideFullscreenParams {

        private final CustomVideoView customVideoView;

        public VideFullscreenParams(CustomVideoView customVideoView) {
            this.customVideoView = customVideoView;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm also using a class named CustomMediaPlayer. This is a singelton that wraps the MediaPlayer and manages its lifecycle all over the app.
It is a MUST if you are loading multiple videos in a RecyclerView or LinearLayout.

Comment: Today I'd have used ExoPlayer(By Google) which is much more mature bug less than MediaPlayer